# Connection closed error while executing query with Spring JDBC Template

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring JDBC template to query SQL Server db. I have a scheduled task configured to execute once every week, below is the implementation:

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public void importData(){

    try{
        logger.debug("Importing Data");
        jdbcTemplate.query(...) // Fails
     catch(DataAccessException e){
        //Log the error
     }
}
```

I am getting the below exception when the task is executed (i.e. once every week):

```
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the Connection object is closed.
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:305)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:329)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory.getErrorCodes(SQLErrorCodesFactory.java:214)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.setDataSource(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:134)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.<init>(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:97)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.getExceptionTranslator(JdbcAccessor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:660)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:727)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:737)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:787)
```

Below is the driver class:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
```

I guess Spring (or jdbc driver) closes the connection if it's idle for configured amount of time. Looking at the implementation of 'query' method, it seems it does not create a new connection. In this case, do I need to use a different method (e.g. `execute`)?

Comment: Your connection pool should deal with this. You have a connection pool, right?

Comment: I am using Spring boot with Jetty, so as per this documentation (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database) it should use Hikari connection pool?

Comment: Only if you include Hikari in your classpath I believe. Not sure what it uses by default.

Comment: Ah right! I will remove jetty dependencies and try to use tomcat to make tomcat connection pool available and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Swapping out a web server to change the JDBC connection pool ... sounds sensible.

Comment: Not sure whether that was sarcasm or an actual input. Will try that anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not Spring that closes the connection but the database that closes it, if inactive for an amount of time. Or perhaps due to a network glitch.

Any connection pool is able to test the connection before giving it to the data-source asking for it. Generally it is done with a test query.

So check if the connection pool is rightly configured.

Comment: I am using Spring boot and hence, it should manage the connection pool? I have the following properties enabled: `spring.datasource.url`,
`spring.datasource.username`,
`spring.datasource.password`,
`spring.datasource.driver-class-name`. Will see whether I need to configure connection pool type as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your dispatcher-servlet.xml add the following line :

```
<context:mbean-export registration="ignoreExisting" />
```

or, If you use annotation, add  :

```
@EnableMBeanExport(registration=RegistrationPolicy.IGNORE_EXISTING)
```

Or, you can add in server.xml (in case of tomcat) `singleton="false"` in your resource :

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
  <Resource singleton="false" ..... />
</GlobalNamingResources>
```